# Expressing a function in terms of power functions

Tags: functions

If we have a function $f(x)$, it is possible that we can express it in terms of an infinite linear combination of power functions of the form $ax^n$. But my question is that why we cannot express it in terms of finite linear combination of those power functions. 
Tag suggested.

Comment: Do you want to give us an example of a function of which you believe should be expressable as a finite linear combination?

Answer (score 2):

Because take for instance

$$f(x)=e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {x^k}{k!}.$$

Then the function $f$ is expressed in terms of an infinite linear combination of power functions, but you can find a finite sum because it only works for polynomials, and $\exp$ is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true that we can express every function as a power series. Try $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\Bbb Q\\0&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$.